Link to the specific line in HTML document
I have an html document inserted in a web page, and my goal is to implement the button which will point to the text with colored background in those doc.
The problem is, I'm not allowed to modify document itself, so I can't add there a <div> tag with an ID.
Is there any way to create a link which points to the special text in html, like style="background-color:#FFC1C1?

No, there is no way to achieve that using HTML alone. You would need to add additional JavaScript.

You can read the page on your server and insert the ID there and embed the page

Use chrome editor and you can Right click, inspect the page and Edit the html in the page to test it. It won't change the original, but atleast you can create the html you want and then send that to the contend editors to update.

Add a button to your webpage that will trigger the JavaScript function
<button onclick="my()">My Button</button>

Create the JavaScript function that will search for the text with the specified style and scroll to it:
<script>
function my() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        var element = elements[i];
        var style = window.getComputedStyle(element);
        if (style.backgroundColor === 'rgb(255, 193, 193)') { // Color in RGB format
            element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'center' });
            element.style.border = '2px solid red'; // Example: adding a border
            break;
        }
    }
}
</script>

